# Why very viscous flow do not dissipate energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy, friction, viscosity

Creeping flows, which are dominated by viscosity, have a lower dissipation rate than any incompressible, continuous motion consistent with the same boundary condition.

This is due to the Helmholtz minimum dissipation theorem.

Intuitevely, it should be the opposite. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: I don't know anything about the helmholtz minimum dissipaton theorem, but the viscous dissipation in highly viscous fluids (like polymer melts and molten glass) is much higher than in low viscosity liquids like water and oil (for the same deformation rates).

Comment: @ChesterMiller I write about creeping viscous flows, flows where inertia is not important, what is the meaning of this theorem?

Comment: That's my understanding of creeping viscous flows.  In the case of molten polymers and glass, the viscosity is typically on the order of 1000 Poise, and inertial effects are not important.  I am not familiar with the Helmholtz theorem, but I do know that viscous heat is important in molten polymer processing, and can affect the temperature of the polymer by several degrees C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem does not state that "very viscous flows do not dissipate energy" nor does it state that more viscous flows dissipate less energy than less viscous flows. It simply states for a given viscosity, and a given set of boundary conditions, the actual velocity field of the flow will minimize the rate of dissipation. This is in accordance with intuition: The actual flow travels the path of least resistance.